# AFTER DELETE, UPDATE trigger not working correctly in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

Something peculiar is happening with one of my triggers. I have built a trigger which will check if the user is attempting to `UPDATE` or `DELETE` a row in the table which has `[Released_Flag] = 'Y'`, and rollback the transaction if that is the case. However, if the user is attempting to update the Released_Flag field from 'N' to 'Y' for a row, it still returns the error.

My trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Prevent_Delete] ON  [dbo].[Data_Test]
AFTER DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @Release_Flag char(1)
    SELECT @Release_Flag = [Release_Flag] FROM deleted

    IF @Release_Flag='Y'
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Cannot update or delete a RELEASED variable.',16,1)
        ROLLBACK
    END


END
```

The above is causing some issues in `UPDATE` statements. It is sometimes raising the error, even if the row being updated has Release_Flag = 'N'. Any idea why this might be happening?

I also used `SELECT * FROM [deleted]` within the trigger to see what is happening, and some rows are showing Release_Flag = 'Y' in the `[deleted]` table, despite them actually being 'N'.

Comment: Maybe it should be `BEFORE DELETE`

Comment: Do you need to cater for multiple deletes as well? What happens if more than one record is deleted at once? This code would error

Comment: You are setting a variable to the value of Released_flag, but as you stated when you select from the deleted table you get multiple rows. So the value of that variable could be from any row in the deleted table. Triggers fire for the entire process, not just one row. This trigger will only work for individual updates or deletes.

Comment: @Leonidas199x If multiple rows are deleted, and only one is flagged 'Y', I still want it to error for all so I am happy with this method.

Comment: @JMabee But if I update one row, from Release_Flag N to Y, the Release_Flag is Y in the [Deleted] table. Any idea this this is? I thought it would be N in the [deleted] and Y in the [inserted].

Comment: @Leonidas199x My issue is it is erroring even when no rows being updated or deleted have Released_Flag = 'Y', and I have no idea why.

Comment: @LucM `BEFORE` is not a valid trigger.

Comment: Your code suffers from a very common flaw - you assume that there is only one row affected by the update/delete/merge statement (and present in the virtual inserted table). Fix it - search the internet for discussions about how to do that. That might fix the problem you are encountering but without a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that is difficult to know.

Comment: In the future, I also suggest you use the SET statement to assign a scalar value if that is your expectation when using a query. If that assumption is violated, it will generate a syntax error which will alert you (or the person using your app) that something terribly wrong has occurred. When you use the select statement for assignment, one of the rows will be used for the assignment but you have no guarantee which row. You might think there is a pattern based on simplistic testing, but there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this that I did not realise is I have another trigger on the table which UPDATES the table. And so the old trigger is firing this new trigger, something I hadn't accounted for.

I have now moved the `AFTER UPDATE` section of this new trigger into my old trigger.